# Pinocchio Lib and Inverse-kinematics

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I am using pinocchio library for a custom 6 axis robot arm (all joints are revolute).
I implemented efficient inverse-kinematics solving as proposed in Pinocchio library tutorial example (https://gepettoweb.laas.fr/doc/stack-of-tasks/pinocchio/master/doxygen-html/md_doc_b-examples_i-inverse-kinematics.html). I modified slightly the example to have robot model built from URDF with all joints definitions including Lower/Upper limits.

So far, I have two problems:

- This cyclic solver implementation does not consider joints limits as some convergences results succeeds with out of range angle for some joints. Is there a solution to integrate joints limits in this cyclic solver?
- This example merges Trans & rotation error (as explained in text). Did someone experience a modification of algo to have independant Position & Orientation errors in convergence process?

Many thanks,

Richard